# Getting data with a similar key name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this data.

```
{"channel":
           {
            "id":*******,"name":"INA229 Measurement",
            "description":"Test with INA229",
            "latitude":"0.0",
            "longitude":"0.0",
            "field1":"Voltage",
            "field2":"Current",
            "field3":"Power",
            "field4":"Temperature",
            "created_at":"2022-04-07T08:40:24Z",
            "updated_at":"2022-04-07T08:40:52Z",
            "last_entry_id":3771},
            "feeds":[]
           }
```

How to take only values for field(x) keys to new data. The key of the name field(x) (field1, field2, field3 ..... field8) is dynamic and varies in the range from **field1** to **field8** keys. I don't know how many there will be in total, even when receiving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `data.channel` with [`for/in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement), check to see if the key starts with the keyword and, if it does, add the value of that property to a new object using that key.

```js
const data = { "channel": { "id": "", "name": "INA229 Measurement", "description": "Test with INA229", "latitude": "0.0", "longitude": "0.0", "field1": "Voltage", "field2": "Current", "field3": "Power", "field4": "Temperature", "created_at": "2022-04-07T08:40:24Z", "fieldTest": "Test", "updated_at": "2022-04-07T08:40:52Z", "last_entry_id": 3771 }, "feeds": [] };

const out = {};

for (const key in data.channel) {
  if (key.startsWith('field')) {
    out[key] = data.channel[key];
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thx. I use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get the key-value pairs of `channel`
- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the latter while updating the resulting object
- In each iteration, use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check for the key format

```js
const data = { "channel": { "id": "", "name": "INA229 Measurement", "description": "Test with INA229", "latitude": "0.0", "longitude": "0.0", "field1": "Voltage", "field2": "Current", "field3": "Power", "field4": "Temperature", "created_at": "2022-04-07T08:40:24Z", "updated_at": "2022-04-07T08:40:52Z", "last_entry_id": 3771 }, "feeds": [] };

const res = Object.entries(data.channel).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if(key.match(/^field[1-8]$/)) {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great example. Thx Bro!

Comment: You're welcome, make sure how do you want to test for the key: whether it should start with `field` or be more accurate about the format by using a regex.